# Приведения типов элементов в списке

Tags: c#, list

Есть список который ходит по коду как тип "Object", но потом нужно из этого списка взять список в котором все элементы будут приведены к базовому типу.
Пример:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object list = new List<B>();

        List<A> list2 = //Тут нужно привести "list"

        //данный метод не подходит:
        //Если будет в объекте другой список,который тоже наследуется от А, будет исключение.
        var list2 = ((List<B>)list).Select(x=>(A)x).ToList();

    }
}

class A
{
}

class B : A
{
}

class С : A
{
}
```

Дело в том, что в этом объекте может хранится список List, С тоже наследуется от класса А.
Спасибо

Comment: А почему «данный метод не подходит:»? Что с ним не так?

Comment: Дело в том, что в этом объекте может хранится список List<C>, С тоже наследуется от класса А. Если будет в объекте другой список, будет исключение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
var list2 = ((List<B>)list).Cast<A>().ToList();
```

---

Обновление: если точный тип списка неизвестен, попробуйте через необобщённый список:

```
var list2 = ((IList)list).Cast<A>().ToList();
```

Учтите, что это даст вам *копию* списка по понятным причинам.

Comment: Дело в том, что в этом объекте может хранится список List<C>, С тоже наследуется от класса А. Поэтому этот метод тоже не подойдет. Если будет в объекте другой список, будет исключение.

Comment: @Scarecrow: понял, обновил ответ

Comment: А почему Cast а не TypeOf? Всмысле, кто его знает, что там внутри.

Comment: @Monk: Ну, ТС говорит, что у него там в реальности `List<T>` для какого-то производного от `A` типа `T`.

Answer (score 3):

Вот так это делается проще:

```
var list2 = ((IEnumerable<A>)list).ToList();
```

Или можно даже не делать `.ToList()` если не нужен доступ по индексу:

```
var list2 = (IEnumerable<A>)list;
```

Но надо отметить, что доступ на запись ни в моем решении, ни в решении выше таким образом получить нельзя.

Comment: Точно! На одну операцию меньше :)